# WordPress reference custom post type in a default WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

For a current project I was wondering if it is possible to reference a custom post type in a default Wordpress blog post.

Example:

I have a blog and on every blog post I would like to call 0 to 2 other blocks, let's name them CTA.

So a CTA can be placed in many posts, and a post can have multiple CTA's.

The question: how to I attach, reference, ... a CTA (custom post type) in a default Wordpress blog post?

I would love to hear some tips, solutions and more.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to accomplish this e.g:

**1. Posts to Posts Plugin:** Use a Post to Post Relationship plugin so you can link, attach, reference any post to any other post or even Custom Post type:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/ (Very stable plugin I have used it with large number of posts and never had an issue) and then you need custom template which fetches to attached posts in second loop.

**2. WP_Query in Short-Code**: You can easily create a short-code for WP_Query which takes parameters and output any specific posts like posts by ID or any other criteria. See this plugin https://github.com/billerickson/display-posts-shortcode

or DIY code https://digwp.com/2010/01/custom-query-shortcode/ or This plugin (Not tested) https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-query-shortcodes-generator/